# Pandas - How to get the number of occurrences for each value in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this csv file called fifa, and it is a record of football player stats.

There is a column, called 'preferred foot' (to kick the ball with), and its values could be either 'left' or 'right' foot only for each record (player).

So what is the fastest way to get a count of the number of players with a right preferred foot, and a left preferred foot.

Example table:

```
# Foot
1 Right
2 Left
3 Left
4 Right
5 Right
6 Left
7 Right
8 Right
```

And from this table, I need the number of players for each of the possible values in the column, so in turn, the above table would be used to create this table.

```
Foot    Number
Right   5
Left    3
```

Please make this general, like what if I were to add multiple values other than left or right to the possible values of the column. Don't limit it to only two possible values for the column.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for DataFrame's histogram function https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `value_counts()` and `reset_index()` methods like

```
new_df = df["preferred foot"].value_counts().reset_index(name="Numbers")
```

Value_counts method counts unique values, and reset_index resets the index to count column (here we name it Numbers)

Comment: Feel free to upvote and accept it as answer if it helps

Comment: can i also ask, what exactly does the name keyword argument do? in reset_index

Comment: You can rename the counts column to any name, like you are doing "Numbers" here

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by and aggregate by count

```
df.groupby(['Foot']).agg({'player_id': ['count']})
```